# Component that allows to change content by date

Tags: android

I want to develop an new android application , by i was wondering if there is some feature or a code availabale that allow me the folowing thing.

[image]

if you see the picture , you can understand what i want , i need some feature or component that can display the current date or any date , with a specific content (if you see the containter under the date) , i also need two buttons that could allow to go forward or backword , each time i change that date i get the correct date with the correct content.

any ideas , so i can figure out from where i can begin.

thanks.

Comment: before putting a -1 at least tell us why ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toolbar widget and inflate your custom layout with Button,TextView,Button.

More info about Toolbar widet here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html